# Ancient Ruins sound on file system?

Tags: civilization-5

Does anyone know the location of the ancient ruins discovery sound? I would like to use it as a ringtone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sounds are (by default) located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Sid Meier's Civilization V\Resource\Common. However, the file type used(.fpk) is designed specifically for 2K Games software which means the file can only be opened by Civ V or software designed to run it.

The easier way is to record the sound while it's playing in game which, fortunately, someone has already done. They wanted that ringtone as well.

[Here are the files in an easy format](https://soundcloud.com/exotic-car-man/sets/ancient-ruin-textones)

[Here's the thread on Reddit, which has some other sounds recorded](http://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/1b2ofk/discover_ancient_ruins_sound/)

Comment: Aren't `.fpk` files just renamed ZIP archives? It's common in other games.

Comment: @DavidHarkness 7Zip wouldn't open it and googling it suggested it is its own file type.

Answer (score -2):

Uploaded it on yt (for everyone who is googling for this)

Comment: This is useless to actually use as a ringtone, though.